# Procedure to move Table information from one server to another one is not working SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a procedure to move information from a server connection which we have to a local database that I've created.
My local database name is Test and we have one server which we connect to with some generic credentials and I use the following query to select my information as that server is linked to a database as well.
When I use the main server with the following query I get the columns that I need:

```
select * from openquery(servicenow, 'SELECT  name, user_name, company,    business_unit, location,manager, email,city, u_world_area, country, Street,    active from sys_user'
```

And I've created the following procedure until now:

```
use Test

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create procedure [dbo].[Update_location] 
as
begin
WITH F AS (
select 
name,user_name, company, u_business_unit, location, manager, email, city,
u_world_area, country, Street, active     
FROM sys_user
),
O AS ( 
select * from openquery(servicenow, 'SELECT 
name, user_name, company, u_business_unit, location, manager,  email,  city, u_world_area, country, Street, active
from sys_user')
)
MERGE INTO F USING O ON F.user_name = O.user_name

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
INSERT (name, user_name, company, u_business_unit, location, manager,  email, city, u_world_area, country, Street, active) 
VALUES (name, user_name, company, u_business_unit, location, manager,  email, city, u_world_area, country, Street, active)

 WHEN MATCHED AND (f.location <> o.location) or (f.manager <> o.manager) then 
 UPDATE SET f.location = o.location, f.manager = o.manager

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
end;
```

I know that something needs to be added in order to make this to work but I don't know what and how, currently getting this error:

> Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Procedure Update_location, Line 5 [Batch
>   Start Line 6]
>
> Could not find server 'servicenow' in sys.servers. Verify that the
>   correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored
>   procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? (That code looks more like MS SQL Server.)

Comment: Maybe try executing the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers

Comment: if I had to guess, you are running on two different environments, one has `servicenow` linked server, the other does not.

Comment: Hey Greg, That is correct, there is no way to move this if i don't get both of the databases linked to the server?

Comment: can this be moved with an SSIS package?